# Laravel4: Chunk function not working with model save()

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, mysql5

I have a query to select all users and hash the password and save that model. Because it times out as there is large data in the DB, I thought I will try chunk() function. My query looks like,

```
    $users = User::where('password','!=','0')->select(array('password'))->chunk(50,function($users){
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $user->password = Hash::make($user->password);
            $user->save();
        }
     });
```

This doesn't save a model. when I try to dump the `$user` variable after `save()` it displays the updated values but when I look into DB it is still unaltered. I tried using `try catch` and `transaction` just to see if it hits any exception during the process, nothing helped. Any help will be appreciated. Also, I don't have $guarded on the `password` field.

Comment: Why don't you `Hash` the passwords when the user is created? Having a non-hashed password in the database (at any point) seems like a bad idea...

Comment: I do that when the user is created. I am doing this because the project I am working on is about to go live and that project was initially in pure PHP hence passwords were never hashed.

Comment: You should also salt the hash. Unless you work for sony :-)

Comment: I believe Laravel 4 already uses salts. Besides, mass updates were working when I was trying to hash the passwords using `wherebetween` query and not using `chunk()` function. I can not use the previous method because I will be on live environment and I don't want to go to the file everytime to change the id's in `wherebetween`. Do you have any solution on the `chunk()` function? or any other method where I will be able to mass update passwords at one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just doing it wrong. Can you tell which row should be updated in that loop? No? Eloquent doesn't know it either, so it runs `update ... where id is null` ;)

Simply add `id` to the `select` clause and it will work (unless you have some magic happening in the `saving` event etc):

```
$users = User::where('password','!=','0')
  ->select(array('id', 'password'))
  ->chunk(50,function($users){
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->password = Hash::make($user->password);
        $user->save();
    }
  });
```